# Linux и PHP: что у нас в директории «/etc/php»?

Tags: php, linux, apache

Директория `/etc/php`:

```
.
└── 7.0
    ├── apache2
    │   ├── conf.d/
    │   └── php.ini
    ├── cli
    │   ├── conf.d/
    │   └── php.ini
    └── mods-available/
```

- `7.0` — версия;
- `apache2` — конфигурационные файлы для Apache-модуля;
- `cli` — конфигурационные файлы для PHP-клиента;
- `mods-available` — конфигурационные файлы установленных модулей;
- `apache2/php.ini` и `cli/php.ini` — главные конфигурационные файлы Apache-модуля и PHP-клиента соответственно;
- `conf.d` — ?

**Зачем директория `conf.d`?..**

<s>Что означает буква `d`?</s> (легко гуглится: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4047/169259), [2](https://askubuntu.com/q/5039/455004))

В ней находятся символические ссылки на конфигурационные файлы доступных модулей (то есть тех, конфигурационный файлы которых лежат в директории `mods-available`). Они почти одноимённые, но с приоритетом, обозначенным в качестве префикса имени ссылки ...

Полный пример:

```
.
└── 7.0
    ├── apache2
    │   ├── conf.d
    │   │   ├── 10-mysqlnd.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mysqlnd.ini
    │   │   ├── 10-opcache.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/opcache.ini
    │   │   ├── 10-pdo.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo.ini
    │   │   ├── 15-xml.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xml.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-calendar.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/calendar.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-ctype.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ctype.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-curl.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/curl.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-dom.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/dom.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-exif.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/exif.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-fileinfo.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/fileinfo.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-ftp.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ftp.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-gd.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/gd.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-gettext.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/gettext.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-iconv.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/iconv.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-imagick.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/imagick.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-intl.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/intl.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-json.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/json.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-mbstring.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mbstring.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-mcrypt.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-memcache.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/memcache.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-mysqli.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mysqli.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-pdo_mysql.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-pdo_pgsql.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_pgsql.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-pdo_sqlite.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_sqlite.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-pgsql.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pgsql.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-phar.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/phar.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-posix.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/posix.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-readline.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/readline.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-shmop.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/shmop.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-simplexml.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/simplexml.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-soap.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/soap.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-sockets.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sockets.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-sqlite3.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sqlite3.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-sysvmsg.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvmsg.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-sysvsem.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvsem.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-sysvshm.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvshm.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-tokenizer.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/tokenizer.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-wddx.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/wddx.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-xmlreader.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xmlreader.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-xmlwriter.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xmlwriter.ini
    │   │   └── 20-xsl.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xsl.ini
    │   └── php.ini
    ├── cli
    │   ├── conf.d
    │   │   ├── 10-mysqlnd.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mysqlnd.ini
    │   │   ├── 10-opcache.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/opcache.ini
    │   │   ├── 10-pdo.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo.ini
    │   │   ├── 15-xml.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xml.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-calendar.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/calendar.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-ctype.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ctype.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-curl.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/curl.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-dom.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/dom.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-exif.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/exif.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-fileinfo.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/fileinfo.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-ftp.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ftp.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-gd.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/gd.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-gettext.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/gettext.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-iconv.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/iconv.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-imagick.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/imagick.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-intl.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/intl.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-json.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/json.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-mbstring.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mbstring.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-mcrypt.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-memcache.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/memcache.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-mysqli.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mysqli.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-pdo_mysql.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-pdo_pgsql.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_pgsql.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-pdo_sqlite.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_sqlite.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-pgsql.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pgsql.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-phar.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/phar.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-posix.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/posix.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-readline.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/readline.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-shmop.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/shmop.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-simplexml.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/simplexml.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-soap.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/soap.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-sockets.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sockets.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-sqlite3.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sqlite3.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-sysvmsg.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvmsg.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-sysvsem.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvsem.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-sysvshm.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvshm.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-tokenizer.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/tokenizer.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-wddx.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/wddx.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-xmlreader.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xmlreader.ini
    │   │   ├── 20-xmlwriter.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xmlwriter.ini
    │   │   └── 20-xsl.ini -> /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xsl.ini
    │   └── php.ini
    └── mods-available
        ├── calendar.ini
        ├── ctype.ini
        ├── curl.ini
        ├── dom.ini
        ├── exif.ini
        ├── fileinfo.ini
        ├── ftp.ini
        ├── gd.ini
        ├── gettext.ini
        ├── iconv.ini
        ├── imagick.ini
        ├── intl.ini
        ├── json.ini
        ├── mbstring.ini
        ├── mcrypt.ini
        ├── memcache.ini
        ├── mysqli.ini
        ├── mysqlnd.ini
        ├── opcache.ini
        ├── pdo.ini
        ├── pdo_mysql.ini
        ├── pdo_pgsql.ini
        ├── pdo_sqlite.ini
        ├── pgsql.ini
        ├── phar.ini
        ├── posix.ini
        ├── readline.ini
        ├── shmop.ini
        ├── simplexml.ini
        ├── soap.ini
        ├── sockets.ini
        ├── sqlite3.ini
        ├── sysvmsg.ini
        ├── sysvsem.ini
        ├── sysvshm.ini
        ├── tokenizer.ini
        ├── wddx.ini
        ├── xml.ini
        ├── xmlreader.ini
        ├── xmlwriter.ini
        └── xsl.ini
```

---

**Конечный вопрос:** зачем нужна директория `conf.d` и её содержимое (+ зачем приоритет)?

Comment: По аналогии с другими конфигами unix могу заключить, что mods-avaliable - это настройки для всех существующих модулей. А conf.d это реально обрабатываемые ini файлы, которые обрабатываются в порядке приоритетов (если одна настройка  с разными значениями в двух файлах, не могу сказать какая итоговая, можно подозревать что последняя, т.е. c большим приоритетом (и далее по алфавиту, внутри приоритета))

Comment: @Mike в этой директории каждый файл отвечает за свой модуль, коллизий параметров там не предполагается

Answer (score 2):

Каждый режим PHP имеет свой набор модулей, например в CLI режиме какой-то модуль не требуется, а на FPM нужен, для этого используют разделяемую загрузку модулей для различных режимов PHP.

Приоритет определяет последовательность загрузки модулей в память. Для начала определимся, с некоторой терминологией:

> Неопределённые или импортируемые имена — функции и переменные, на
>   которые ссылается модуль, но не определяет их внутри себя;

Предположим, **модуль** ссылается на **pdo** и использует его, если этот модуль будет загружен раньше чем pdo, случится ошибка подключения библиотеки из-за того что импортируемое имя не найдено в памяти, т.к. при обработке не будет найден класс или функция на которую ссылается этот модуль.

Приоритет загрузки позволяет решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Что-бы включать/выключать модули не трогая их конфиги.

Например надо тебе что-бы в апачёвом php не было модуля `pdo_pgsql` — удаляешь симлинк на его конфиг из apache2/conf.d/, надо вернуть его обратно — заново создал симлинк. А если-бы там лежали сами конфиги то пришлось-бы напрягаться с его восстановлением или надеяться что правильный конфиг для apache не отличается от правильного конфига для cli.

Такая организация подобных конфигов — распространённая практика как минимум в некоторых дистрибутивах GNU/Linux.

Зачем нежны приоритеты именно тут — не знаю. Могу предположить что для разруливания зависимостей между модулями (хотя не думаю что они там есть).